# To find the limit of $\lim_{t \to 0} t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}.$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

To find the limit of $$\lim_{t \to 0} t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}.$$

We know that $$\ln(\lim_{t \to 0} t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}) = \lim_{t \to 0} \ln(t^{\frac{t}{t-1}})$$

which implies $$\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t}{t-1} \times \ln(t).$$

But after that I am getting confused.

Comment: $t\ln t \to 0$ as $t\to 0+$.

Comment: Rewrite $t^\frac{t}{t-1}$ as $\exp(\frac{tln(t)}{t-1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the substitution $u= 1/t$. Then as $t\to 0^+$ it follows that $u\to\infty$. Then
$$
\lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{t}{t-1}\ln t= \lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-\ln u}{u-1} =0
$$
by an application of L'hopital's rule.